# Number field limitation

Tags: cognito-forms

I have set up a form for our parents to complete, the field asks for the students passport number but it will only them allow to fill out a certain amount of numbers. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The number field is not always the best for this kind of data, as there is a limit to the size or number that can be added. We suggest that you use a Text field with the format validation set to 'Numeric'. You can learn more about this in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/44/building-forms/form-field-reference/textbox-field).